# I am using Instagram's API to obtain Reel's `ig_reels_avg_watch_time`, but what is the unit of this value?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am using Instagram's API to get Reel's `ig_reels_avg_watch_time`, but what is the unit of this value?
When I try to get it, I get the value `3755` even though the reel is about 1 second.

Comment: Documentation doesn't say what unit. It does however say that this metric is still in development, and https://business.facebook.com/business/help/metrics-labeling says about that, _'When you look at a metric's definition, you may see language that says, "This metric is in development." An in development metric is a measurement that we're still testing. We're still working out the best way to measure something, and we may make adjustments until we get it right.'_ - so this might(!) at this point simply be a metric that doesn't actually give useful values yet.